# Integrate highcharts in vtiger?

Tags: vtiger

I am trying to change vtiger graph look to highchart look. but i am new for vtiger, so help me out to change vtiger graph layout.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated Highcharts in vTiger with custom dashbaord.

Please follow below steps to integrate highcharts in vTiger:

- Include all highcharts JS files
- Add new tpl file
  /layouts/vlayout/modules/Home/Dashboards/customreports.tpl and
- include it in DashboardPreProcess.tpl file
- Your JS file should be look like this:

  ```
  jQuery.Class("Home_ChartView_Js",{
  },{
  lead_by_status : function(){

      var form=jQuery('#frm_slreport');

      form.find('.btn_sl_report').on('click',function(e){
          console.log("Click");
      var sl_fromdate  = form.find('[name="sl_fromdate"]').val();
      var sl_todate  = form.find('[name="sl_todate"]').val();
      console.log(sl_fromdate);
      console.log(sl_todate);

              /* AJAX CALL */

      var progressIndicatorElement = jQuery.progressIndicator({
          'position' : 'html',
          'blockInfo' : {
          'enabled' : true,
          'elementToBlock' : jQuery('#sl_report')
      }
      });
      var params = {};
      params['module'] = 'Accounts';
      params['parent'] = '';
      params['view'] = 'LoadChartData';
      params['mode'] = 'loadChart_lead_by_status';
      params['edate'] = sl_todate;
      params['start_date'] = sl_fromdate;
      //console.log(params);

      AppConnector.request(params).then(function(data){
              var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
              var fdata=returnedData.result.fdata;
              console.log(fdata);
                                  //fdata=JSON.parse(fdata);
              var data1=[{
                              name: 'Counter',
                              colorByPoint: true,
                              data: eval(fdata)
                         }];
              $('#sl_report').highcharts({
                      chart: {
                      type: 'column'
                      },
                      title: {
                      text: sl_fromdate+' to '+sl_todate
                      },
                      xAxis: {
                      type: 'category'
                      },

                      legend: {
                      enabled: false
                      },

                      plotOptions: {
                      series: {
                          borderWidth: 0,
                          dataLabels: {
                              enabled: true
                          }
                      }
                      },

                      series: data1,
                      drilldown: {}
              });

              progressIndicatorElement.progressIndicator({mode : 'hide'});
      });



              /* AJAX CALL */



  });
  },
  });
  ```
- `btn_sl_report` id should be present in customreports.tpl
- Update the view file with the function names which you mentioned in Ajax call.

Hope it will help you to integrate the highcharts in vTiger.

Answer (score 0):

which diagram do you mean?
although you can check these files:

> *VTRoot->*/modules/Dashboard/horizontal_bargraph.php 
>   *VTRoot->*/modules/Dashboard/vertical_bargraph.php 
>   *VTRoot->*/modules/Potentials/Charts.php

for lead by source:

> *VTRoot->*/modules/Dashboard/Chart_pipeline_by_lead_source.php

Comment: I have changed this but I want to integrate highcharts to vtiger crm.

Comment: In stack you go and in case of hitting the wall, you ask! Your entry is not a question, it's a mini project I think. I integrated it with fusion charts and it's some how drudgery job, with lost of testing!

Answer (score 0):

Go to layouts/vlayout/modules/Vtiger/resources/dashboards/Widget.js

You will see the Chart code there. Remove the current library code and add Highchart code there. You will get data from Vtiger. You should prepare the data for Highchart and update there as well.